# Can't get a route displayed with leaflet-machine-routing in React

Tags: reactjs, routes, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to display a simple route from point A to point B with leaflet-machine-routing and react-leaflet, but it just won't work.

Map.js:

```
import {React} from 'react';                                                     
import {Map, Marker, Popup, TileLayer} from "react-leaflet";
import L from "leaflet";
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import "leaflet-routing-machine";
import '../App.css';
import {iconUser} from './icons/userIcon';

function MapDefault(props){

const position = [57.74, 11.94];
const position2 = [57.6792, 11.949];

const map = (
    <Map center={position} zoom={15} scrollWheelZoom={false} style={{ height: '100vh' }} ref={saveMap}>
        <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />            
        <Marker position={position} icon={iconUser}/>

        <Marker position={position2} icon={iconUser}>
            <Popup>
                Hello world!
            </Popup>
        </Marker>
        <GetARide />
        
    </Map>
)

   const control = L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
      L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
      L.latLng(44.00939, 18.25666)
    ]
  }).addTo(map);

return(
    <div>
        {map}
    </div>
)
}


export default MapDefault;
```

I'm new to all this so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: do you use react-leaflet version 2?